# how can I change the background color of the header using an alertDialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter

currently only the text is only painted with the following code

[image]

```
AlertDialog(
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
   title: Text(
     'Error',
     style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: STYLES.styles["success"]),
   )
   .
   .
   .
```

I would like to paint the header of the alertDialog in one color, how can I do it?

Comment: Did you try to put a row as the title? Then, you can put an expanded inside that row and it will take up the whole space. Then color your expanded widget.

Comment: I tried it but I am unable to paint the whole header.   https://i.imgur.com/6KoT32e.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Container as the `title`.

There's a `titlePadding` property for `AlertDialog`. If `title` isn't null, the default value is 24. therefore you need to explicitly supply it with 0.

```
AlertDialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
  title: Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Text('Error'),
  ),
  titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
)
```

Comment: thanks, but I am getting this problem: https://i.imgur.com/6KoT32e.jpg  What I tried to ask is to try to paint the whole header, that is, from the top edge to where the title is

Comment: What's your full code, mine looks fine https://imgur.com/5ChdCLY

Comment: Thanks for your help...  https://i.imgur.com/YucX4mD.jpg  I don't know what I was doing wrong, but now for some reason the rounded edge at the top is missing, you know why?

Comment: Maybe there's something to do with the `FadeInDown` widget

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
AlertDialog(
    title: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: const Text(
        "Error",
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    content: const Text("Message"),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      MaterialButton(
        child: const Text("Accept"),
        onPressed: () {},
      )
    ],
  ),
  barrierDismissible: false,
);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OouHI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the title inside a `Container` and align it with `center`.

Try something like this..

```
 AlertDialog(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
  title: Container(
  color: Colors.orange,
  child: Center(
    child: Text("Error"),
 )),
 titlePadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
 )
```